# The ticks will be hidden when I want to show the Legend in Plot3D, how to solve it?

Tags: plotting

When I use Plot3D, the ticks are hidden when I wanted to show the legends. Is there any way to solve it?

```
Plot3D[{Sin[x^2 + y], Cos[x^2 + y]}, {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, ViewPoint -> {1.6, 2.4, 1.6}]

Plot3D[{Sin[x^2 + y], Cos[x^2 + y]}, {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, ViewPoint -> {1.6, 2.4, 1.6}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set `SphericalRegion -> False`.

The default setting is `Automatic`, which is `False` when the graphic is on its own, but flips to `True` when it's in another construct (`Legended`, in this case.)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)
```

The axes are on the edges behind the plot. Explicitly place the axes on the desired edges using the option [`AxesEdge`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxesEdge.html)

```
Plot3D[{Sin[x^2 + y], Cos[x^2 + y]},
 {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi},
 ViewPoint -> {1.6, 2.4, 1.6},
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 AxesEdge -> {{1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]